# Return value from VB6 exe Main?

Tags: vb6, program-entry-point

I'm getting the impression this isn't possible, but here's what I've got so far.

```
Sub Main()        
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler        
    If Command$ = "" Then
        LogAction "Begin document lockdown"
        LockdownDocs
        LogAction "Lockdown complete"
    Else
        LogAction "Begin document enabling"
        EnableDocs
        LogAction "Documents have be enabled"
    End If
Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    LogAction "DocLock Error " & Err.Number & "::" & Err.Description
End Sub
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
Function Main() As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler        
    If Command$ = "" Then
        LogAction "Begin document lockdown"
        LockdownDocs
        LogAction "Lockdown complete"
    Else
        LogAction "Begin document enabling"
        EnableDocs
        LogAction "Documents have be enabled"
    End If
    Return True
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
    LogAction "Error " & Err.Number & "::" & Err.Description
    Return False
End Function
```

The closest I've seen is `Function Main() As Integer` in Visual Studio 2005, but I'm using VB6.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a possible solution [here](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=794886), by using a Win32 API call.  In essense:

```
Private Declare Sub ExitProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal uExitCode As Long)

' Exit with ErrorLevel set to 9
ExitProcess 9
```

Note that this is the equivalent of `End` to the VB runtime so you must do any cleanup, closing of connections, files, devices, forms, etc before calling `ExitProcess`.

Comment: Beautiful, elegant solution.  Thanks much!

Comment: +1 but make sure you've done ALL the cleanup you can, closing and releasing all objects, setting everything to `Nothing`, etc,

Comment: Indeed, @Deanna is correct - this call will immediately terminate the process I believe, so make sure everything is de-initialised that needs to be.

Comment: @NickShaw: I've adding a line to the answer to make that point.

Comment: I only recently discovered that this wasn't working correctly on Windows Server 2000.  It will throw an error message saying "The instruction at 0x######## referenced memory at 0x########.  The memory could not be read."  Microsoft doesn't support this for VB6, but explains a possible, though not perfect, workaround is to call `CoUninitialize` immediately before `ExitProcess`. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288216